# creating a product score value

Tags: html, css

im new to css and html i wanna cr8 a product box value like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPKTD.png

I tried with these but didn't get any result.
I want `.fill` class to be dynamically modifiable.
Anyone can help me ?

```css
.box {
  width: 250px;
  height: 30px;
  background: grey;
  color: white
}
.box .fill {
  float: left;
  width: 78%;
  background: orange;
  height: 100%;
}
.box .empty {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  right: 10px
}
.box .fill-badge {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 10px;
  line-height: 30px
}
.box .empty-badge {
  padding-right: 10px;
  line-height: 30px;

}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="fill"><div class="fill-badge">Radeon 7870</div></div>
  <div class="empty"><div class="empty-badge">125.6 GB/S</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: what's fill-badge, what's empty-badge?

Comment: text badge of orange score , and empty is text of unit score that i want to be right side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to look at your `absolute` and `relative` positioning.  Make sure that all elements that are absolutely positioned are inside an element with relative defined as a position.  So in this case you just need to add `position: relative;` to the .box.

```css
    .box {
      width: 250px;
      height: 30px;
      background: grey;
      color: white;
      position: relative;
    }

    .box .fill {
      float: left;
      background: orange;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .box .empty {
      float: right;
      white-space: nowrap;
      right: 10px
    }

    .box .fill-badge {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      padding-left: 10px;
      line-height: 30px
    }

    .box .empty-badge {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      padding-right: 10px;
      line-height: 30px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="fill" style="width:60%;">
    <div class="fill-badge">Radeon 7870</div>
  </div>
  <div class="empty">
    <div class="empty-badge">125.6 GB/S</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edited to show inline style.**

Comment: it's doesnt show 125.6 GB/s unit when fill's width sets to +60%

Comment: Not sure if you posted this before i edited, but works with .fill at 60%

Comment: Changed to 60% in the demo.

Comment: how can i use it with dynamically values ? like 90% or 100% i want at this scores shows unit thanks

Comment: Setting the width with CSS almost prevents this.  You have to either use JS and read from an data-attribute etc.  Or you can inline style `width: 60%;` and have the number set on page load, i am updated the example to show this.

Comment: when i set something value like 90 10 5 100 % it's works well thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would do it using a **background color** and a **background image** for the same element like:

```css
.box {
    width: 240px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    background: #fa0 url(http://placehold.it/250x300/aaa) 200px 0 no-repeat;
    color: white;
}
.box span{
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    Radeon 7870 <span>125.6 GB/S</span>
</div>
```

Comment: works but i cant change the value score background , i want it dynamically

Comment: @jessieomline you mean the orange one? :) have you tried to invert the logic? (gray background at 200px left and orange background color?)

Comment: @jessieomline ... edited. now you can dynamically change the `#fa0` color.

Answer (score 0):

You must set the .box position to relative. http://jsfiddle.net/Lzmop76a/

```
.box {
    width: 250px;
    height: 30px;
    background: grey;
    color: white
    position: relative;
}
```